# Unable to understand Terraform "interpolation" technique or method

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm unable to understand what is the issue with the below interpolation for terraform to produce Error out?

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-cluster" {
 count               = 2
 name                = "${ax_base_hostname}-ni-${count.index}"
 location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster.location}"
 resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster.name}"

 ip_configuration {
   name                          = "testConfiguration"
   subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-cluster.id}"
   private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    }
}
```

Error message below:

```
terraform :
At line:1 char:1
+ terraform plan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error: azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster: 2 error(s) occurred:
* azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster[0]: invalid variable syntax: "ax_base_hostname". Did you mean 'var.ax_base_hostname'? If this is part of inline `template`
parameter
then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
example: ${a} becomes $${a}.
* azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster[1]: invalid variable syntax: "ax_base_hostname". Did you mean 'var.ax_base_hostname'? If this is part of inline `template`
parameter
then you must escape the interpolation with two dollar signs. For
example: ${a} becomes $${a}.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a very descriptive error message.  Which part of it did you not understand?

Comment: Error fixed, it was in error message. Should use var.

Comment: delete this questing on this case

Answer (score 0):

Error fixed, it was in error message. Should have used `"${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index}"`